# SIMBA JDBC DRIVER + BIGQUERY + SPRING BOOT + application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-bigquery

I have connected bigquery to my spring boot application using simba drivers and successfully queried to get the resultset. My problem is i have configured everything in the class file.

my bigquery connection code sample:

```
Connection connection = null;
DataSource ds = new com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.DataSource();
ds.setURL("jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;<project-id>;OAuthType=0;<service-account>;OAuthPvtKeyPath=<path-to-key-file>;");
connection = ds.getConnection();
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(*) as numberRec from project.table;");
System.out.println("before querying table======================>");
while(rs.next()) {
System.out.println("================totalrows==============="+rs.getString("numberRec"));
}
```

while connecting with a mysql or postgres database we can configure datasource information in the application.yml as follows:

```
spring:
  datasource:
      platform: postgresql
      continue-on-error: true
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      separator: ^; 
      url:  "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database"
      username: "postgres"
      password: "postgres"
```

Is it possible to configure the bigquery connection in application.yml as well?

Comment: I am trying to connect BigQuery from spring boot, But I am running into some issues. It is throwing Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Simba][JDBC](10100) Connection Refused: [Simba][JDBC](11640).Can you please share your git repo by hiding your credentials.

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the GitHub repo as it belongs to my previous company. And on top of that, I don't have access to it anymore.